# Silverlight 5 Toolkit XNA samples don't seem to work

Tags: silverlight, xna, toolkit

I'm trying to run the XNA samples on the Silverlight 5 toolkit package. the sample opens up the browser with the HTML folder contents in it rather than the Xap itself. clicking on the HTML does not open the XAP either. I had to solve a compile problem in the samples by adding this to the .contentproj file manually.

```
<PlatformTarget Condition=" '$(PlatformTarget)' == '' ">x86</PlatformTarget>
```

My question is, is it a problem with my configuration? what should I do to ensure I don't have deployment problems? has anyone faced this problem before?

Update:
I set the default browser to IE and I got GraphicsDevice = null because of this reason RenderModeReason = GPUAccelerationDisabled and I enabled it, and went into silverlight configuration to allow driver acceleration and I get SecurityBlocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable ElevatedTrust and run it at OOB only and it worked. but kinda seems pointless if I cannot run it in the browser.